# How to load script content without execution?

Tags: javascript

I have a path to the script as a string:

```
var path = 'some_script.js';
```

it could be either remote path, relative or absolute, from the same or from a different origin:

```
var path = 'http://path.to/some/another_script.js';
```

I'm trying to find a way to load a script with the given `path` without execution and get it's content as a string.

I was trying to create a `script` with invalid type in order to later fetch its content with some DOM functions:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = path;
s.type = "text/broken";
//    s.type = "text/javascript";

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

But in this case the script is not even loaded (at least in Chromium). If I change it's type to `"text/javascript"` the script is loaded, but immediately executed.

Is there any way to load a script without an execution, and get its content?

Comment: So make an Ajax request and fetch the file.

Comment: thx, will try to do like this..

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a normal AJAX call, which goes something like this:

```
function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", path, true);
oReq.send();
```

If you're using JQuery then you can do this instead:

```
$.get(path, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The OP mentions fetching from different domains, so it should be noted that this will only work if the source domain is willing to cooperate and provides appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: But normal script loading via `script` tag do not require any special cooperation from a server of another origin, right? This means either you load the script **and** execute it, or you cannot load it at all.. a bit wired I think

Comment: I think that without the right CORS headers you probably wouldn't be able to load a script from another domain even in a `script` tag. The restriction is imposed by the browser though, so it's not unimaginable that it might restrict some types of cross-site content but not others.

Comment: As far as I understand, before CORS headers the only way to load data from another origin is JSONP which is in fact loading data using `script`